# Updating appSettings.json from controller method in .NET core

Tags: asp.net-core

I am new to .NET core and I am trying to set my connection string from the Login method in the AccountController, based on the specific user that logs into my application. I know I can get the current values using the following;

```
string DefaultConnection =_iconfiguration.GetSection("ConnectionStrings").GetSection("DefaultConnection").Value;
```

However, I am having trouble updating the connectionstring to the appropriate one when a new user logs in.

I'm sure I am missing something fairly simple, but if someone could help I would be very grateful.

Comment: Why do you want to update connection string in the configuration based on the user who is logging in? What would you do if there's 20 users logging in at the same time? Configuration is a singleton, so this doesn't sound right.

Comment: inside your app, you should consider any configuration sources (like  `appsettings.json`) as a read-only sources only.

Comment: That's a good point. To give you some background. I am trying to implement this in .NET Core.

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/848111/Multi-Tenancy-System-With-Separate-Databases-in-MV

If you can suggest a workable approach that would be great.

Comment: What I don't think I made clear initially is that the users are all going to be logging into an accounts database. After that the user's data should come from their companies "specific" database.

Comment: I have 2 DataContext files and 2 different connectionstrings in my appsettings.json file. The default one connects to the Accounts database and stays consistent.

Each company then has it's own distinct database which is identical in structure for all companies. I use the second datacontext for this. What I need is for the database name in the connectionstring to change depending on the specific user, so they access the database of the company they work for.

Comment: So... I understand that it is bad practice to update the appSettings.json from the controller method. What about defining a new connectionstring based on the user that logs in, to make sure they are only accessing their company's data? 

If not, can someone suggest a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

Security concerns aside, if you need a dynamic string that has values changing based on a condition (such as user logins), you could just implement something simple such as:

```
string ipAddress = "127.0.0.1" // maybe grab this from your appsettings.json?
string username = "foo";
string password = "bar";
string connectionString = $"server={ipAddess};uid={username};pass={password}";
```